# Best way to capture multiple matches

Tags: ruby, regex

Having in same text message fixed part once (id of item) and multiple lines (several references and dimensions of each part):

```
..some random text here..
ID/11000082734
REF/D14-109-0
REF/D14-209-0
REF/D14-219-0
CMT/59-40-25
CMT/38-25-28
CMT/59-40-25
CMT/37-37-20
CMT/40-40-20
CMT/37-37-20
CMT/49-41-31
CMT/44-34-53
```

I want to parse and store `IdCode`, `References`, `Array with dimensions`.

When applying `REGEX.match(my_text)` method getting only first occurencies of `REF` and `CMT`:

```
REGEX = %r{
ID\/(?<IdCode> \d{10})\s 
(REF\/(?<ReferenceCode> \w{3}\-\d{3}\-\d)\s)+ 
(CMT\/(?<Length> \d+)\-(?<Width> \d+)\-(?<Height> \d+)\s)+
}x
```

The result looks like this:

```
IdCode: "1100008273"
ReferenceCode:  "D14-219-0"
Length: "37"
Width:  "37"
Height: "20"
```

Is there a way to capture multiple occurrences without iterating ?

Comment: Your regex does not match the string you provided. Please update/clarify what you are actually doing.

Comment: I think it is not possible

Comment: Trying to do a multi-line regex is not always a great idea, do the easier thing of parsing line by line my be the right thing to do

Comment: @JoeHalfFace: it's possible, but bjhaid approach is better.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, why is bhhaid's approach better?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Happy to see you! Because with a line by line approach (using `each_line`) you only need to use basic and fast string methods (like `split`) with literal characters (in this case you only need to know what is the first field to know what to do). Other thing, when the datas come from a file, the benefits can be impressive: ruby loads a part of the file in a buffer (to limit disk accesses and to use few memory at the same time) and then the buffer provides a line. After some tests, I realize that this underlying mechanism allows the line processing tasks to work in parallel.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: in short, it is slower to load the whole file and to process each lines after. (I assume that the data come from a file, but most of the time, people loads the whole file and ask a question after.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: When I said "it's possible" in my first comment, I was thinking of a pattern with the `\G` anchor, but the main problem with this approach is that you need to load the whole file, and that you need to group elements of a same item together in fine.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your string were:

```
str = %w| dog
          ID/11000082734
          REF/D14-109-0
          REF/D14-209-0
          CMT/49-41-31
          CMT/44-34-53
          cat
          ID/11000082735
          REF/D14-109-1
          REF/D14-209-1
          CMT/49-41-32
          CMT/44-34-54
          pig |.join("\n")
```

```
  #=> "dog\nID/11000082734\nREF/D14-109-0\nREF/D14-209-0\nCMT/49-41-31\nCMT/44-34-53\ncat\nID/11000082735\nREF/D14-109-1\nREF/D14-209-1\nCMT/49-41-32\nCMT/44-34-54\npig"
```

Then you could write:

```
r = /(ID\/\d{11})                     # match string in capture group 1
    \n                                # match newline
    ((?:REF\/[A-Z]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d\n)+) # match consecutive REF lines in capture group 2
    ((?:CMT\/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\n)+)   # match consecutive CMT lines in capture group 3
    /x                                # free-spacing regex definition mode 

arr = str.scan(r)
  #=> [["ID/11000082734", "REF/D14-109-0\nREF/D14-209-0\n",
  #     "CMT/49-41-31\nCMT/44-34-53\n"],
  #    ["ID/11000082735", "REF/D14-109-1\nREF/D14-209-1\n",
  #     "CMT/49-41-32\nCMT/44-34-54\n"]]
```

This extracts the desired information without iterating.

At this point it may be desirable to convert `arr` to a more convenient data structure. For example:

```
arr.map do |a,b,c| 
  { :id  => a[/\d+/],
    :ref => b.split("\n").map { |s| s[4..-1] },
    :cmt => c.scan(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/).map { |e|
              [:length, :width, :height].zip(e.map(&:to_i)).to_h }
  }
end
  #=> [{ :id=>"11000082734",
  #      :ref=>["D14-109-0", "D14-209-0"],
  #      :cmt=>[{ :length=>49, :width=>41, :height=>31 },
  #             { :length=>44, :width=>34, :height=>53 }
  #            ]
  #    },
  #    { :id=>"11000082735",
  #      :ref=>["D14-109-1", "D14-209-1"],
  #      :cmt=>[{ :length=>49, :width=>41, :height=>32 },
  #             { :length=>44, :width=>34, :height=>54 }
  #            ]
  #    }
  #   ]
```

Comment: That's quite a solution, but second parsing/split/gsub is required. The idea was to get match data with one `scan`. Probably it's not possible.

Comment: I Woo, I disagree. You said, "I want to parse and store `IdCode`, `References`, `Array with dimensions`." and "Is there a way to capture multiple occurrences without iterating?". Does `str.scan(r)` not do those two things? If you want to convert the result to a different data structure that is obviously done as a subsequent step. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?<IdCode>\d{10,})|REF\/(?<ReferenceCode>\w{3}\-\d{3}\-\d)|CMT\/(?<Length>\d+)\-(?<Width>\d+)\-(?<Height>\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ4kL1/1)

**Explanation:**
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)

Input

```
..some random text here..
ID/11000082734
REF/D14-109-0
REF/D14-209-0
REF/D14-219-0
CMT/59-40-25
CMT/38-25-28
CMT/59-40-25
CMT/37-37-20
CMT/40-40-20
CMT/37-37-20
CMT/49-41-31
CMT/44-34-53
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
IdCode  [29-40] `11000082734`
MATCH 2
ReferenceCode   [45-54] `D14-109-0`
MATCH 3
ReferenceCode   [59-68] `D14-209-0`
MATCH 4
ReferenceCode   [73-82] `D14-219-0`
MATCH 5
Length  [87-89] `59`
Width   [90-92] `40`
Height  [93-95] `25`
MATCH 6
Length  [100-102]   `38`
Width   [103-105]   `25`
Height  [106-108]   `28`
MATCH 7
Length  [113-115]   `59`
Width   [116-118]   `40`
Height  [119-121]   `25`
MATCH 8
Length  [126-128]   `37`
Width   [129-131]   `37`
Height  [132-134]   `20`
MATCH 9
Length  [139-141]   `40`
Width   [142-144]   `40`
Height  [145-147]   `20`
MATCH 10
Length  [152-154]   `37`
Width   [155-157]   `37`
Height  [158-160]   `20`
MATCH 11
Length  [165-167]   `49`
Width   [168-170]   `41`
Height  [171-173]   `31`
MATCH 12
Length  [178-180]   `44`
Width   [181-183]   `34`
Height  [184-186]   `53`
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim007, Actually it's works. Was wondering if could be done within one `$~`, getting somehow array of `REF`..

Comment: @I Woo I don't think so